# Is there any available function in numpy that iterate a ndarray and modify each element with a custom function?

Tags: python, numpy

```py
def evolve(self):
    newgrid =signal.convolve2d(self.grid, self.neighborhood, 'same')
    dimentionX = self.grid.shape[0]
    dimentionY = self.grid.shape[1]
    for i in range(0, dimentionX):
        for j in range(0, dimentionY):
            if newgrid[i,j] < 2:
                self.grid[i,j] = self.deadValue
            elif newgrid[i,j] == 3:
                self.grid[i,j] = self.aliveValue
            elif newgrid[i,j] > 3:
                self.grid[i,j] = self.deadValue
    return self.grid
```

I am doing something like this. This function is frequently called. It was fine when the grid is not large (64x64 for examplee). However, when the grid has with more than a thousand, the simulation runs very slow.

I was told that with appropriate use of numpy it should be much more faster. I was told that numpy provides such a function that does the same thing as what I have written, but much faster.

After some research at the documentations, I only found this:
[image]

But this only support boolean return type, and only support simple callback for each element, while I need to do complex operation (that is multilined and involves 'if's) for each element

Comment: Wouldn't an [apply](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html) do just what you want ?

Comment: What about `newgrid[i,j] == 2`?

Comment: @user12932966, `apply_along_axis` is a way of applying a function to 1d elements of a higher dimensional array.  It makes iteration over a 3d (or higher) array prettier, but not faster.  It doesn't help here.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks, I didn't know that. I'm afraid I'm using too much pandas and too little numpy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>*Note that I do not discuss you approach as such. I strictly address your question.*</sub>

---

What about resorting to [boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) ? As follows

```
# [...]
self.grid[(newgrid < 2) | (newgrid > 3)]  = self.deadValue
self.grid[newgrid == 3] = self.aliveValue
# [...]
```

?

Answer (score 0):

The function is `np.where`

```
def evolve(self):
    newgrid = signal.convolve2d(self.grid, self.neighborhood, 'same')
    self.grid = np.where(newgrid == 3, self.aliveValue, self.deadvalue)
    return self.grid
```